# Meteor Issue : 0.6.6.3: unknown release

Tags: meteor

How to solve `0.6.6.3: unknown release` issue in `Meteor`?. When i am get this is error is **Running Meteor Project in command prompt**. I didn't get any Idea about this.So please see the below issue environment and suggest me what to do?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

E:\***\Meteor\demo>meteor
0.6.6.3: unknown release.
```

Comment: Which version of meteor did you install?

Answer (score 0):

If your meteor application has been developed with another release and you want to run it, you'll see a filed named `release` in your `.meteor` folder within your project.

Windows version of meteor is not official so you'll need to run your project without locking it down to a release.

You can replace the `release` file with an empty one.

Also make sure you are running the latest windows version, or better yet, take a look at [nitrous.io](http://nitrous.io)